# opencv for iOS: cvHoughCircles result is not the same on iPhone and simulator

Tags: ios, opencv

I have an issue with Opencv library for iOS. When using `cvHoughCircles` the result on simulator is different from iPhone's. Here is the code

> CvSeq *circles = cvHoughCircles(   gray, //Input image
>
> ```
>                                storage, //Memory Storage
>                                CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, //Detection method
>                                2, //Inverse ratio
>                                gray->width/8, //Minimum distance between the centers of the detected circles
>                                100, //Higher threshold for canny edge detector
>                                20, //Threshold at the center detection stage
>                                gray->height/6, //min radius
>                                gray->height/2 //max radius
>                                );
> ```

`circles->total` = 0 on simulator but 1 on iPhone. Here is the image[image]

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: are you using a different way to obtain your Mat gray object if you are on simulator than if you are on the device?

Comment: no. The same way. I have recognized that the image is shifted 4 or 5 pixel to the right (on simulator) when crop an iplImage.